# How to set up Network Request Class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I'm trying to set up a class called NetwortRequests where I do all my calls to Parse. Trying to figure out how to get the results out of this class and into the class where I'm calling this method. Thanks!

```
class NetworkRequests: NSObject {

   class func retrieveCandidatesWithCompletion(complete: (result: NSArray) -> Void) {

      let query = PFQuery(className:"Customer")

      query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
         (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

         if error == nil {

           // The find succeeded.
            print("This is object: \(objects)")

            // populate results
            complete(result: objects!)

               }
            }

         } else {

            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: whats the problem that you are having

Comment: Can't figure out how to get the array out of here to set a different array in another class I'm calling this method in. Objective C is easier for me to conceptualize.

Comment: `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
         (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
` is no longer usable , you have use the `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
         (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new parse SDK the completionHandler Block does not return `objects:[AnyObject]?` but they returned `objects:[PFObject]?`.
So try this:

```
class NetworkRequests: NSObject
 {

   class func retrieveCandidatesWithCompletion(complete: (result: NSMutableArray) -> Void)
   {
    let query = PFQuery(className:"Customer")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil
        {
            var dataToExtract:NSMutableArray = []
            if let objects = objects
            {
                // The find succeeded.
                print("This is object: \(objects)")
                // populate results
                for SingleObject in objects
                {
                    let username = SingleObject["username"] as! String
                    dataToExtract.addObject(username)
                     complete(result: dataToExtract)
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I actually got stuck with this for a while. It is [AnyObject]?, not [PFObject]?. This changed with swift 2.0 apparently. But my problem arises because I believe that I'm setting the objects (results) in the array. Then I wanted to set this array to another array in the view controller where I want to use this data. I can't get to the data though, I'm wondering if I'm just not using the swift closure syntax correctly (I have much more experience with Obj C).

Comment: are you using parse new sdk

Comment: Basically, I pull down all the data correctly in the network requests class, but how can I use this data in the View Controller where I call this retrieveCandidatesWithCompletion:?

Comment: are you using the new parse sdk , and what do you have inside of the PFObject ( ex: username)

Comment: I am using new parse sdk. I have strings in the object, the data comes back as an array of dictionaries, one dictionary for each entry.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a delegate protocol (with a method like receivedAllData( data:Array ) and use that in the NetworkRequests class in the completion block.
You then implement the delegate in the viewcontroller class and you can update it (textfields, etc) when the completion block is finished and calls the delegate method.
Delegates are a very powerfull way of sending data around in your projects. Apple use them all the time also :-)